# Importing a newer Apache HttpClient jar in Android

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to send an HTTP/HTTPS post request from my Android client.

### Question

Why does my code fail?

### So far

I created an apache class/HttpClient call. Everything worked fine:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

I've read that this method has been deprecated, so I've switched to the new recommended method:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

Eclipse didn't have this class, so I had to download Apache HttpClient 4.3.3. I imported it to my project by copying it into the `libs` folder and adding them to my build path (imported httpclient, httpclient-cache, httpcore, httpmime, fluent-hc, commons-logging, commons-codec).

### Error message

```
06-05 02:15:26.946: W/dalvikvm(29587): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;' failed
06-05 02:15:26.946: E/dalvikvm(29587): Could not find class 'org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager', referenced from method org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build
```

### Most recent code

```
static private String insertJson(String json,String url){
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    String responseString = "";
    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        StringEntity params =new StringEntity(json, "UTF-8");
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");

    }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        // handle exception here
    } finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: It may be deprecated in a more recent release of the library. However Android uses an old version. I don't think it's deprecated in Android.

Comment: @matlash There's a difference between deprecation and complete removal.

Comment: @EJP But the "new suggested method" (`HttpClientBuilder`) doesn't even exist in Android. It's new in httpclient 4.3, while android has 4.0beta2. `DefaultHttpClient` was not yet deprecated in that version, and is not deprecated in Android either.

Comment: Aren't there any previous warnings in logcat when the apk is loaded? Some classes may fail to load because _previous_ classes failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Android already includes an older version ([it's unclear exactly which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618573/what-version-of-apache-http-client-is-bundled-in-android-1-6/4818714#4818714), but around 4.0beta2) of Apache HttpClient.

When you add the jars of the new version as libraries of your application, duplicate classes are ignored when the APK is loaded. Since some *new* classes in HttpClient depend on *modifications* made on these other classes, dalvik does what it can (e.g. removing references, &c) but unless they are used conditionally, this is likely to cause crashes.

For example, you can see messages like these in logcat:

```
06-05 00:46:39.083: I/dalvikvm(6286): Could not find method org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestDefaultHeaders.<init>, referenced from method org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build
06-05 00:46:39.083: W/dalvikvm(6286): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 22794: Lorg/apache/http/client/protocol/RequestDefaultHeaders;.<init> (Ljava/util/Collection;)V
06-05 00:46:40.434: D/dalvikvm(6286): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler;.INSTANCE
06-05 00:46:40.434: W/dalvikvm(6286): VFY: unable to resolve static field 8420 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler;
```

This particular message is because `DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler` [has a new INSTANCE static field in 4.3](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler.html), which [it does not have in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler.html). There are many more.

Going back to your original question, the only way to use a newer httpclient would be to rename *all* classes so these name conflicts don't occur. This is what [httpclientandroidlib](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/) does.

Going even further back: DefaultHttpClient [has indeed been deprecated](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) in 4.3, but it is **not** deprecated in Android (unless you consider the [trend towards using HttpUrlConnection](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) a stealth form of deprecation -- in which case a newer HttpClient wouldn't be the preferred alternative either). Why exactly would you want/need to change it?

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, now I do understand why the error occurs. I need to use newer HttpClient since I have problems with HTTPS certifications (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048419/android-https-post-fails-on-newer-devices)

Answer (score 0):

One year answer, correct answer is to use official android port of apache libraries which uses different namespace and so avoids collisions: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html