# Http methods deprecated warning in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, deprecated, androidhttpclient

I am trying to make some http request with parameters. Currently I am using

```
 private List<NameValuePair> mParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 private DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient;
 private HttpPost mHttpPost;
```

these for making http request and it is working fine. But the problem is android studio is showing deprecated warning for all
    these 3 . I tried by using 
`HttpClientBuilder.create().build();` but android studio cannot import the libraries for `HttpClientBuilder`
  I tried downloading and adding  [this jar dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0-alpha4)   but still doesn't work.   This is my code

```
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        mHttpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", value));
        mHttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(mParams));
```

All these lines are showing deprecated warning, which is the alternative method for this?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049197/sending-an-http-post-request

Comment: HttpClient is deprecated use HttpUrlConnection. Check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android deprecated apache module (HttpClient, HttpResponse, etc.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294479/android-deprecated-apache-module-httpclient-httpresponse-etc)

Answer (score 5):

You can use  `HttpsURLConnection` instead of `DefaultHttpClient`. Also `NameValuePair` is deprecated,  use `Uri.Builder`  and `appendQueryParameter` to send request parameters.

Try following piece of code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://myurl.com");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
       .appendQueryParameter("key1", valu1)
       .appendQueryParameter("key2", value2);
String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
       new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(query);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
connection.connect();
```

Answer (score 2):

DefaultHttpClient class is deprecated instead you can use HttpUrlConnection class . HttpUrlConnection hassimple API . NameValuePair class  may be deprecated in api 22. You can Use ContentValues (android.content.ContentValues)  instead of  NameValuePair.

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("Param_name1", Param_value1);
        contentValues.put("Param_name2", Param_value2);
```

I am using Okhttp client to make get and post call. http://square.github.io/okhttp/

I think this link will help you 
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html

Answer (score 1):

[from this link](https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)  you can download the latest jar for httpclient4.5. and use

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient` is deprecated since API `level 22`. Prefer `HttpURLConnection` for new code.

Android includes two HTTP clients: HttpURLConnection and Apache HTTP Client. Both support HTTPS, streaming uploads and downloads, configurable timeouts, `IPv6` and connection pooling. Apache HTTP client has fewer bugs in Android 2.2 (Froyo) and earlier releases. For Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) and later, `HttpURLConnection` is the best choice. Its simple API and small size makes it great fit for Android. Transparent compression and response caching reduce network use, improve speed and save battery. See the Android Developers Blog for a comparison of the two HTTP clients.

Answer (score 1):

IDE prompts warning on ***new DefaultHttpClient***, mark this class as deprecated **[deprecated in Api 22]**.

To solve it, use [HttpClientBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html) :

```
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```