# Android SSL - No Peer Certificate (GeneXus)

Tags: android, json, ssl, https, genexus

I get a 'No Peer Certificate' error when I run my android app:

> 08-25 18:09:11.212: D/Genexus-HTTP(23639): Request (GET) to https://system.funacc.com/gxmetadata/happyplus.android.json 
>   08-25 18:09:11.342: E/Genexus-HTTP(23639): Error (javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException) from https://system.funacc.com/gxmetadata/happyplus.android.json
>   08-25 18:09:11.342: E/Genexus-HTTP(23639): javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
>   08-25 18:09:11.342: E/Genexus-HTTP(23639):  at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:146)
>   08-25 18:09:11.342: E/Genexus-HTTP(23639):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
>   08-25 18:09:11.342: E/Genexus-HTTP(23639):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:388)

I've created my android app using [GeneXus](http://www.genexus.com)
Do I need to configure anything on GeneXus to use https rest services?

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason to get this error is that the certificate is invalid or not a CA root validated certificate.

If you’re using a test/temporary certificate, this could be reason. If you think the certificate is valid please check if the server is returning the full certificate chain.

Please check related thread:

[SSL certificate is not trusted - on mobile only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862908/ssl-certificate-is-not-trusted-on-mobile-only)

and

https://superuser.com/questions/347588/how-do-ssl-chains-work

Comment: I would suggest adding this to this answer: If and only if you have no chance to use that services "as is", then add this to the MainApplication.java file:
application.setAllowNotTrustedCertificate(true);

Comment: Note that, in the case you set that flag in MainApplication.java, your app, and may be your app's users incur in major security risks.

Comment: Great! something was wrong my certificate on server side. Thanks guys!