# SSL handshake failing for custom domains in AWS-API-GATEWAY for some mobiles

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-api-gateway

In AWS-API-Gateway, I created a custom domain using Letsencrypt certificates. My apis work for some of the mobiles but fails for most. After debugging in mobile, I found this particular issue in one of the mobile

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [SSL certificate is not trusted - on mobile only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862908/ssl-certificate-is-not-trusted-on-mobile-some) some mobile devices may have more strict enforcement in the ordering of the certificate chain. You may need to follow up with LetsEncrypt directly on this one.