# SSL error on iOS mobile Chrome, Firefox, Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl

I have website with SQL certificate from StartSSL. It work's fine on desktop browsers, but on several mobile browsers I see security error. I See error on iPhone 6+ and iPhone 7, on old iPhones and Android devices it works fine. 
I checked this topic and other: [SSL certificate is not trusted - on mobile only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862908/ssl-certificate-is-not-trusted-on-mobile-only)
On SSLlabs my server has A rate - no vulnerability founded, cert is OK. 
https://whatsmychaincert.com/ say that all good.

Could you please help? Where is my error? 
Sorry for my english.

Url of website: https://bv app dot ru  (without spaces, dot = .).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I received answer from StartSSL support team.

Hello,

It is because of the latest Apple news.
Apple surprisingly very quickly distrusted our certificates issued after 30.11.2016.
We are aware of the issue and are working hard to fix it.

Best Regards
StartCom™ Certification Authority