# Android SSLHandShakeException: Handschake failed on Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

Since a week when doing a request, I get this SSLHandschakeException. Have been searching the internet, found nothing to solve the problem. The code used to work, and stopped working wihout a change. The SSL certificate is valid, it works in the browser, also on the Android device. But not in the app.

I run the app on a Nexus 5 with Android 6.0.1. The app uses Volley to make the requests, just normal stuff.

The weirdest thing is, when removing the app from the device, and than run the app, it works. But after that is doesn't.

The complete stacktrace:

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:151)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
      at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:396)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103)
      at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
      at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
      at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:501)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:110)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112) 
    Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
      ... 16 more
      Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
        ... 16 more
      Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
        ... 16 more
      Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xab1e5c00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:100c543e:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0xab4705c0:0x00000001)
      at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
      at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xab1e5c00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:100c543e:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0xab4705c0:0x00000001)
      at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
      at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
      ... 15 more
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xab1e5c00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:100c543e:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0xab4705c0:0x00000001)
      at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
      at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
      ... 15 more
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xab1e5c00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:100c5410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0xab4705c0:0x00000001)
    error:100c009f:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_hello:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c:750 0xab23259f:0x00000000)
      at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
      at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
      ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1582#issuecomment-97104082

You could be in one of those situations:

1. > You go to a site called *https://example.com* and you end up on a site that
   >   to you appears to be on *https://example.com* but is giving you a
   >   certificate for *https://no-example.com*. OkHttp will correctly fail the
   >   connection. In a browser like Chrome you'd see a warning in the console along the
   >   lines of "This isn't the page you think it is"
2. > Other exceptions showed that a certificate was provided by the server,
   >   but it wasn't trusted because the root certificate wasn't on the
   >   client device (or may have expired)

You need to debug more your SSL problems, probably due to a wrong certificate configuration on server or a missing/expired certificate on the client. You can try to follow something similar to [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1582#issuecomment-95979104) when you have understood where is your problem

Comment: Hi MatPag, thank you for the reply. 1. We checked this, certificate is valid (also on Chrome). We did ask our certificate supplier if they know something. 2. Do you know how to debug missing/expired certificate on the client?

Comment: You should be able to find on internet some examples on how to get the certificate, and match it against the ones installed on your client to see if it is missing. In this case you should manually add the certificate to the trusted ones. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862908/ssl-certificate-is-not-trusted-on-mobile-only) if can be of any help